# unit testing double digit fails

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, tdd, nunit

I am testing a Variance method(unit) but double issue is occuring.

```
    public double Variance()
    {
        return Probablity * (1 - Probablity);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Variance_WithSuccessProbablity02_Returns016()
    {
        var bernoulli = new BernoulliDistribution(0.2);

        Assert.AreEqual(bernoulli.Variance(), 0.16);
    }
```

This test result is returns fail. 
**Failed: Expected: 0.160000000000003d But was 0.16d**

Comment: Now the real note: What is your question?  You're aware that this is a "double issue" - what do you want us to do about it?

Comment: well `0.2d * 0.8d` is not exactly 0.16d ! ! but using a decimal can help fix this

Comment: Have a look at my response below, it should give you the code update you need. And don't forget to accept it if it works :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NUnit, you can either compare floating point values using an explicit tolerance:

```
Assert.AreEqual( double expected, double actual, double tolerance );
```

or you can globally set `GlobalSettings.DefaultFloatingPointTolerance` to a non-zero value (by default it is 0.0).

There is more information on floating point comparison [here](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=equalityAsserts&r=2.6.1).

In your specific case, I recommend you to try this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(bernoulli.Variance(), 0.16, 1.0e-9);
```

Answer (score 1):

Such precision issues often arise when using floats or doubles.

You need to allow for a small "variance" from your variance (excuse the pun).

Answer (score 1):

```
Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(bernoulli.Variance() - 0.16d) < 0.00001d);
```